# Azure Automation RunAs account access to Active Directory resource

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to create a Runbook which does some maintenance in Active Directory. On creation of an Automation Account an "RunAs" account was created. In the runbook I connect to AD using the below command.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

"Logging in to AzureAD..."
Connect-AzureAD `
 -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
 -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
 -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
 -LogLevel Info
```

This command runs fine, however the subsequent use of AD CMDLETS gives the following error,

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser
```

```
Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. 
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden 
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden 
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

The same is true for other CMDLETS in the AD module, not just this I have tried adding API permission through the registered application (relating to the Automation Account connection resource) in Active Directory but I am still facing the above privileges issue.

Comment: Have you grant the admin consent after adding the permission in registered application in AD ?

Comment: Yeh I have granted admin consent for a set of API permissions in this case those relating to reading users - User.Read, User.Read.All, User.ReadBasic.All

Comment: And did you add _application permissions_? Delegated permissions won't work in this context.

Comment: @felix I test it in my side(connect with service principal) and meet the same issue with you. I will do some research and come back.

Comment: Hi @felix May I know if the permission I mentioned below can solve your problem ?

Comment: Hi, yeh maybe, I have it working now but honestly I don't know what fixed and now I have removed all API permissions and it still works

Comment: Not sure if that permission alters the login in some way

Comment: @felix Yes I also meet the same situation with you, it still can get the AD users when I remove the `Directory.Read.All` permission. Then I do some more test with creating new service principal(registration app) to connect to AD. I also re-open powershell every time to ensure no cache or session impact. The test result is only when add the AD graph permission `Directory.Read.All` it can run the `Get-AzureADUser` command success. So I think this permission is the point to impact the authorization although we don't know why it still can list the users after removing this permission.

Comment: I found in another test that I just needed to add the three PrivilegedAccess.Read.x permissions for Microsoft Graph and that also seemed to work

Comment: Hi @felix Are you sure you can get users after adding the three `PrivilegedAccess.Read.x` permissions for Microsoft Graph ? I test it in my side(with creating a new service principal) and it still can't get users after adding the three permissions. Is it possible still because of you have added the `Directory.Read.All` permission and then removed it ?

Comment: Ah yeh, so I think you are right, I have accepted your answer. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some test, you need to add the permissions of Azure AD but not Micorsoft Graph. It seems the `Get-AzureADUser` command use Azure AD graph in the backend. So we need to do the operations as below:
[image]

[image]

After that we can use the command `Get-AzureADUser` successfully(**if you test the command in powershell, when you add the Azure AD permission, please close the powershell and reopen it and re-connect**)